# how can I enable x-11 forwarding in pycharm? when connecting to vagrant or a remote ssh?

Tags: ssh, vagrant, pycharm, x11-forwarding

I am using pycharm in windows but the python backend need to be running on unix so I host the python app/code in ubuntu with vagrant, however I need to do some plotting as well, is there a way I can enable matplotlab plotting in pycharm with vagrant？ thanks

Answer (score 8):

Try to set DISPLAY environment variable in PyCharm run configuration like this:

```
DISPLAY=localhost:10.0
```

I got my display value from vagrant ssh connection

```
vagrant@vagrant:$ echo $DISPLAY
localhost:10.0
```

Comment: Do you need to have XMing of similar X server running on Windows?

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone stumbles upon the same issue.. There are several ways for you to enable X11 through PyCharm.

The solution for me was to **create a terminal session using the -Y flag** (or -X), e.g.:

```
ssh -X user@ip
```

or

```
ssh -Y user@ip
```

The -Y worked for me as it enables trusted X11 forwarding, which are not subjected to X11 Security extension controls ([ssh man page](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/ssh1.html))

You also need to **export DISPLAY** variable just like [user138180](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32945380/3501630) said

For me the **matplotlib backend** that worked was "*tkagg*". See [matplotlib faq](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html) for more info.

---

My remote machine is a centos 7. My local machine is running Manjaro.

A workaround to having the terminal session opened is to follow what Tarun said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47146093/3501630).

---

As an example, (thanks, [user138180](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6543500/tamtam)), you could use this code to test if it works:

```
import matplotlib matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt plt.interactive(False)

plt.hist(np.random.randn(100))
plt.show()
```

Comment: This worked for me local MacOSx and remote Ubuntu. Additionally, here were my lines of code:  `import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
plt.interactive(False)
    plt.hist(np.random.randn(100))
    plt.show()`