# PyCharm how to remove SciView

Tags: pycharm

My [google search](https://www.google.com.vn/search?newwindow=1&ei=U-llWo63OYK58QWF4aKQCA&q=pycharm+how+to+remove+SciView&oq=pycharm+how+to+remove+SciView&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i71k1l4.0.0.0.3572551.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c..64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.3D8kZz388m4) and search in PyCharm plugins list results as little helpful

So I raise it here, how to remove SciView pane in PyCharm?

[image]

Answer (score 36, accepted):

1. Under Settings => Tools => Python Scientific
   Uncheck the (only) box `"Show plots in toolwindow"`. Future plots should appear "normally" and not in SciView.
2. To remove from the side panel entirely, right click on the SciView tab, and select "Remove from Sidebar".

Comment: The main frustration is that if you just "Remove from Sidebar", it always comes BACK on the next IntelliJ/PyCharm launch. It doesn't persist. I believe option #1 above does keep it gone across re-launches :)

Comment: Haven't tried that before, but lack of settings persistence across reboots in IntelliJ tools does happen to me. It is rather annoying :\

Comment: I just tried only #2 "Remove From Sidebar" on IntelliJ, then saw the restart comment, restarted, and the removal persisted, still gone after the restart! W00T! That has annoyed me since day one of IntelliJ, finally gone!

Comment: It may still leave your run configurations using the option "Run with Python Console" after you turn it off that way, it doesn't really fully revert back to normal mode in that sense.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to generally keep SciView and only disable it for a specific project, you can also force the default backend:

```py
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
```

This can also be useful to force the backend on collaborators if specific functionality is needed.

Answer (score 6):

You either get out of Scientific mode by unchecking it:

[image]

or click to close the panel on top right (->|) if you want to remove just the panel.

Comment: It will come back at next reboot of Pycharm

Answer (score 5):

You can easily disable SciView in PyCharm and display the normal output of matplotlib by unchecking "Show plots in tool window" found in the following steps (My PyCharm version is 2019.3 Mac OS):

1- Go to "Preferences":

[image: Go to Preferences]

2- Go to "Tools" then "Python Scientific":

[image: Go to Tools then Python Scientific]

---

As a remark: the output images may close immediately with `plt.show()` so you may add `plt.hold(True)` to hold the output in Python.

Your test code might be:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
plt.ylabel('random test numbers')
plt.show()
plt.hold(True)
```

Comment: `AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'hold'`