# Pycharm dataframe or array in new window

Tags: pycharm

Before I upgraded to pycharm professional, I was able to get all my dataframes as separate windows.

Now my dataframes are in sciview, all aggregated into a single window with multiple tabs. I can't compare them side by side, and it is quite frustrating.

How can I disable the sciview functionality?

This question works for plots, but not for view as array / view as dataframe - [Using PyCharm I want to show plot extra figure windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48334853/using-pycharm-i-want-to-show-plot-extra-figure-windows) .

Desired:
[image]

Currently:
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyCharm how to remove SciView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48384041/pycharm-how-to-remove-sciview)

Comment: Nope, I mentioned it in the question that I did that, and it didn't work :)

Comment: I've got the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is

1. Click the window icon in SciView to Open in Editor Tab
2. Once the dataframe is in the Editor tab, right click the tab name and click "Move to New window"

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you can click on the "Open in Editor Tab" button to achieve what you want. Once the dataframe appears in the main area, you can then also drag and drop it outside and move it / position it independently. I am now comparing dataframes side by side whilst using the Professional edition by doing this... after scratching my head for a while.

Comment: true, but it's just not the same unfortunately. it's an okay compromise