# PyCharm, open new window for each "View as DataFrame"

Tags: python, pycharm

In Debug mode, I would like PyCharm to open a new window (*not* a new tab!) for every "View as DataFrame" click I do.

[image]

Right now, they are opened as tabs, which makes it very difficult to compare.

[image]

[Other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68254196/pycharm-dataframe-or-array-in-new-window) suggest to klick the "Open in editor" button to then move it. This works but it is annoyingly cumbersome. And I remember in the past multiple windows opened (maybe in the community edition?)

Comment: on my side, when I click "View as datafrane" it does open it in a new modal window. are you saying you would like multiple windows, or tabs? I assume you are in debug mode.

Comment: yes indeed, I clarified the question in this right.

Comment: when I click on every "View as Dataframe" for each df, they actually show up. but one was hidden by the other. Modal view seem to be only for the code.. have a check and I can send a screen copy if you like.