# Disabling SciView in PyCharm Professional

Tags: pycharm

I am using PyCharm Professional edition 2021.2.3. By default all the data and plots pop-up in the "SciView" window. To stop plots from appearing there, I have followed the steps from an answer to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48384041). However, my data still comes up in the same window. See attached image below.
[image]

Is there a way I can totally remove Sciview and use the old fashioned sub-window like the ones in the CE version (see below attached image)?
[image]